# XMPP chat architecture

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, xmpp, chat

I am currently connecting to an external XMPP server (not mine). Since I couldn't find any XMPP PHP client which suits my needs, I have developed my own simple client ([XMPP PHP)](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/xmpp-php). The client opens a socket connection to the server and that is where the XML exchange happens, and that part works well.

The main reason for developing this package was to integrate it within a corporate app. I have done so and can successfully send messages back and forth.

Even though my end goal is to have an open websocket connection, currently the program works by polling the server in 2s interval (I am using a simple 1on1 communication, no chat rooms or similar):

```
receiveMessages: function () {
    this.poll = setInterval(function () {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url     : 'index.php',
            method  : 'post',
            params  : {
                method: 'receiveMessages',
            },
            scope   : this,
            callback: function (options, success, response) {
                ...
            }
        });
    }, this.pollTimer);
}
```

And on the PHP side:

```
public function receiveMessages()
{
    $messages = $this->client->getMessages();

    if ($messages) {
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            $message = $this->xml2array($message);

            $conversation = $this->conversationExists($message['@attributes']['from']);
            if ($conversation == null) {

                $preparedConversation = array(
                    ...
                );

                $conversation = $this->_save($preparedConversation ...);
            }

            $message = array(
                ...
            );

            $response = $this->_save($message ...);

            return array(
                'success'  => true,
                'response' => $response,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Upon success, this method updates frontend with the received message, as well as saves the message to the DB. DB is organized in a way that one `User` can have many `Conversations` and one `Conversation` can have many `Messages`.

What I fail to understand though is how should everything be structured in order to function like some of the real chat clients (Facebook or other messengers), because this way I can't get the "concurrency" I want. If I log in with my account on 2 different places, each of them will poll the server every 2s, and it is basically a race condition, first one to get the message will display it.

If I think about it, one way to do it properly would be to implement websockets to server, and have frontend wait for DB changes, however I think this may create much read overhead on DB. Can someone give me some advice on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) will help. Especially the HTML5 IO Sockets and keeping the connection "alive".

Comment: I have already read that article before...even though its helpful, it does not quite answer the architecture question. Also, bare in mind since it is a corporate app, I have to be compatible with previous versions and all browsers

Comment: using the`complete` method in ajax, keeps the server alive by reexecuting the method. You do not need to use HTML5 if you do not want, but there is a section dedicated to keeping the server alive with JS in that article

Comment: I understand, but server I am connecting to is not mine. And keeping the connection alive isn't my concern, I want to know how to construct it on the client side with regards to my app and DB